# Create new column with unique ID to handle duplicates from 2 columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe consisting of surveys that are done for specific subjects on specific days.
Looking something like this:

| subject_id | day | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 34 |
| 02 | 1 | 54 |
| 03 | 3 | 55 |
| 04 | 4 | 56 |

However, sometimes the survey is done two times in a day, resulting in duplicate Subject_id and Day values, but different data (in reality the data spans multiple columns).

| subject_id | day | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 34 |
| 01 | 1 | 58 |
| 02 | 1 | 54 |
| 03 | 3 | 55 |
| 04 | 4 | 56 |

The dataframe is sorted by time, such that the second row represents the second survey on day 1 for subject 1. What I would like to do is to add a column called name that adds "- 2" to every second duplicate subject_id and day and adds nothing (or "- 1" is also acceptable) for non duplicates. In the end the data should like this.

| subject_id | day | data | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 34 | 1 |
| 01 | 1 | 58 | 1 -2 |
| 02 | 1 | 54 | 1 |
| 03 | 3 | 55 | 3 |
| 04 | 4 | 56 | 4 |

I have tried using dplyr and janitor to mark the duplicates. However after many hours I still failed to make the new column as described.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df <- fread("subject_id day data
01  1   34
01  1   58
02  1   54
03  3   55
04  4   56") %>% 
  tibble()

df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   subject_id   day  data
#>        <int> <int> <int>
#> 1          1     1    34
#> 2          1     1    58
#> 3          2     1    54
#> 4          3     3    55
#> 5          4     4    56

df %>% 
  group_by(subject_id) %>% 
  mutate(name = ifelse(order(day) == 1, 
                       as.character(order(day)), 
                       paste(day, "-", order(day)))
         )
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#> # Groups:   subject_id [4]
#>   subject_id   day  data name 
#>        <int> <int> <int> <chr>
#> 1          1     1    34 1    
#> 2          1     1    58 1 - 2
#> 3          2     1    54 1    
#> 4          3     3    55 1    
#> 5          4     4    56 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work, but has some unintended effects when more duplicates are in the dataframe. For a given day a maximum of 2 surveys are done. This scripts seems to keep counting after 2,  and is not based on the day. For example with 2 duplicates in the data it adds a 3 to the second duplicate. Even if this is not on the same day as the previous duplicate.

Comment: After changing 
group_by(subject_id) to group_by(subject_id, day)
this now works perfectly! many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df |> group_by(subject_id , day) |> 
   mutate(name = ifelse( duplicated(day) , paste0(day , "-" , cumsum(duplicated(day))+1)
 , as.character(day)))
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this solution to work. I get the error:
Error in duplicated(day) : object 'day' not found

Answer (score 0):

If `survey` are your data as `data.frame`

```
duplicatedresults<-duplicated(surveys[,c("subject_id", "day")])
surveys$name[duplicatedresults]<-paste0(surveys$subject_id[duplicatedresults],"-2")
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, this marks every duplicate subject_id. Maybe my example was not clear enough, but any subject_id can have multiple days, without being a duplicate. Only when its 2 rows with the same subject_id AND day should it be seen as duplicate.

Comment: It is corrected now to check for both subject_id and day

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  mutate(name = janitor::make_clean_names(subject_id, use_make_names = FALSE))


# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   day [3]
  subject_id   day  data name 
       <int> <int> <int> <chr>
1          1     1    34 1    
2          1     1    58 1_2  
3          2     1    54 2    
4          3     3    55 3    
5          4     4    56 4
```